# The Tomcat debug port suddenly falls

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos

When I connect to Tomcat jpda port, it suddenly falls (Tomcat still works but debug port is not up)

The server of Tomcat is centos and Tomcat config (in catalina.sh ) is :

```
export JPDA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4004"
```

Is this config correct?

Comment: What exactly does a falling jpda port look like? Any error msgs in logs/console or when connecting?

Comment: no , we have not any log in catalina.out , just after few time working with debug mode and port , without any error the port were down